# загрузка изображения через ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

js:

```
let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
let method = "GET";
let url = "upload.php";
let asynchronous = true;

ajax.open(method,url,asynchronous);


ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
      let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      for(let key of data){
      let info = document.createElement('img');
      let jsContent = document.querySelector('.JavaScriptContentLoader')
      info.src = key.img;
      jsContent.append(info)
      }
   }
}
ajax.send();
```

php:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","pharmacy");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pharmacy");
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $data[] = $row;
}
if (!$conn) {
   die('Ошибка при подключении: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

как записать ссылку в БД чтобы не выдавало ошибки при выводе на страницу?

Мои попытки были такими:

> C:/Users/юзер/OneDrive/123/openserver/OSPanel/domains/localhost/php/css%20medical/img/original_036aa95f-1f0f-44aa-b526-0f26b5510d67.jpeg
>
> http://localhost/C:/Users/юзер/OneDrive/123/openserver/OSPanel/domains/localhost/php/css%20medical/img/original_036aa95f-1f0f-44aa-b526-0f26b5510d67.jpeg

Comment: определить правильный путь от корня движка/php-скрипта

Comment: я писал правильный путь, но то не работало

Comment: C:/Users/имя твоего акка/OneDrive/твоезначение/openserver/OSPanel/domains/localhost/php/css%20medical/img/original_036aa95f-1f0f-44aa-b526-0f26b5510d67.jpeg

Comment: код php-скрипта добавь

Comment: Таки он в шапке... :\

Comment: там нет никакого кода, который сохраняет имя файла в БД

Comment: так мне просто нужно вывести уже json файл из бд

Comment: не правильно сформулировал вопрос